# API for monitoring new music

Tags: api, music

Is there any API that has endpoints for monitoring when artists release new music? Right now I'm resorting to using Apple Music or Spotify's API's to monitor all the songs that are listed under whichever artist I'm interested in, and looking for additions to that list every day.

Doing this for many artists seems like it would be painful (The most computationally efficient way I can think of doing it would be to store the list of songs for each artist every day and then do a diff of the current day's list and the previous day's list, every day, but this causes problems if a song is renamed), so I was wondering if there is an API that could easily give me the information I'm looking for. Something like a RESTful API where I could interact with `https://MusicAPI.com/artists/{artistID}/songs/newReleases` to get songs (or /albums/newReleases for albums) released in the past 24 hours by that artists. (Maybe the country or music service would need to be included in the url because I'm fairly certain that some songs are released at different times for different countries and different music services).